# Номер телефона аккаунта в инстаграм

Tags: php, javascript, instagram, instagram-api, web-scraping

Есть id, username и ссылка на аккаунта, необходимо узнать номер телефона владельца. В instagramm-scrapper порылся в абстрактных моделях, и даже не нашел намека на данную функцию. Есть ли возможность по описанным данным, узнать телефон на который зареган аккаунт?

Comment: Никак, в Facebook не идиоты сидят, чтобы отдавать такую информацию наружу.

Comment: И к тому же совсем не факт, что акк зарегистрирован на телефон.